# LXD containers isolation problem?

Tags: ssh, firefox, security, lxc, lxd

I am playing with LXD containers, and fail to completely understand what is happening with isolation. Here is my scenario:

1. create a 16.04 container `launch ubuntu:16.04 mycontainer`
2. install firefox within it `lxc exec mycontainer /bin/bash` and `apt install firefox`
3. create a user with the same name as my main system user `adduser myuser`
4. ssh-copy-id to that user `vi /etc/sshd_config` to allow ssh with password, then from main session `ssh-copy-id myuser@mycontainer-ip`
5. ssh -X into the container and launch firefox `ssh -X myuser@mycontainer-ip` and `firefox`

If I have no Firefox opened in my main session, an isolated Firefox pops up: no access to my main session files, no plugin, etc...

But, if Firefox is already running in my main session, launching FF from my ssh -X session in the container opens another FF window that is not isolated and runs as my main user (with my plugins, access to files, etc...).

What is happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened a bug report on lxd's github and Stéphane Graber gave me the answer: this is *a feature of Firefox*, that can be toggled off with the `--no-remote` switch. So of course ***no problem with LXD*** !

Quoting Stéphane:

> I've not used firefox in a long time, but I believe they have code to
>   find and interact with an existing firefox through X properties.
>
> Since you pass "-X", your container has access to your X server and so
>   can query/set X properties, list all running windows, ... which is
>   most likely how firefox detects an existing firefox session and has it
>   open a new window rather than spawn a new process.
>
> I'd expect there to be a command line option to firefox to have it not
>   do that.

se https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3049

So launching `firefox --no-remote` from the container prevents firefox from opening a new window in my main session.